# Twilio post sms using HttpClient

Tags: c#, twilio

I'm trying to post data to the Twilio Rest API to trigger a sms sendout.

I've tryed to do what is instructed to do with cURL but with HTTP Post insted.

```
https://AccountSID:AuthToken@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AccountSID/Messages
```

Then in the body I post data looking like this:

```
public class TwilioMessage
{
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

I'm getting `StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'UNAUTHORIZED'` all the time. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Instead of including your credentials in the URL you should set them using the DefaultRequestHeaders property:

```
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password1234");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
```

Hope that helps.